# IIS6 can not connect with sql server 2008

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am doing a simple application in asp.net and `sql server 2008`, my application is perfectly working with `visual studio 2010`.
but when i deploy same application on `Internet Information Services(IIS)` then it shows m error saying that

```
" Login Failed for user sumit-3A81ED\IUSR_ sumit-3A81ED".
```

is there anything that i need to do??
please help me

thanks

Comment: what is actually happens here is that visual studio runs under your account (probably administrator) and your asp.net site (IIS) runs under the pools account. So you need to find what is the account that your pool runs, and then give this permission to connect with the DB.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555332 or  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2008/05/03/understanding-the-error-message-login-failed-for-user-the-user-is-not-associated-with-a-trusted-sql-server-connection.aspx or http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/88/posts/10159/sql-server-quotlogin-failed-for-user-username-the-user-is-not-associated-with-a-trusted-sql-server-c.aspx might help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should enable Mixed mode authentication on SQL Server, create a Login and User in the database accessed by your web application, and specify this user in your connection string.

Answer (score 0):

seems that your connectionstring is incorrect..
update server name and login credentials in the connectionstring